# ConnectionError: Connection not yet open

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I using nodejs + SQL Server. It's working fine but sometime 5% connection

```
const dbConfig = {
user: process.env.USR,
password: process.env.PWD,
server: process.env.SRV,
database: process.env.DBNAME,
options: {
    trustedConnection: true,
    encrypt: false,
    enableArithAbort: true,
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    synchronize: true,
    instancename: process.env.INSTANCENAME
  },
  port: Number(process.env.DBPORT)
}
```

interactive with database.

```
const dbConfig = require('./dbConfig');

let pool = await sql.connect(dbconfig);

let resultData = await pool.request()
                        .input('Param1', sql.VarChar, data.Param1)
                        .input('Param2', sql.Int, data.Param2)
                        .execute('SP_Query_Info');

pool.close();
```

As of above coding, I sometime found this error occurs in log and need to optimize.

```
ConnectionError: Connection not yet open.
at ConnectionPool._acquire (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\topup_backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\connection-pool.js:298:36)
at ConnectionPool.acquire (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\topup_backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\connection-pool.js:284:56)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\topup_backend\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:770:19)
at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21) {
  code: 'ENOTOPEN'
}
```

I am finding the best way to optimize. Any suggestion please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [mssql documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connection-pools) yet? You seem to be calling `.close()` on the connection pool, not individual connections, which is likely to be causing your problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I had read it but I am not much understand english and I got the coding from a blog I am remember it.

Comment: I have the same error, but in my case I work with a legacy project that uses sails-mssql (currently latest version without support use mssql 6.2.0), getting periodic 'Connection not yet open' errors, the same request works fine in 98%, but sometimes this error is thrown. I tried setting connection pool in config file, but doesn´t works.